# Pain with Maven and Java env variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, maven-3

So I installed Java following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04) as I did many times, and set `$JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`, `java -version` works fine.
After that I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-maven-linux-ubuntu) as I did many times and install maven. I don't understand why I need to add to `.profile` `JAVA_HOME` once again but I always did and it worked, so I do it again and add at the end of the file lines:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
M2_HOME='/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4'
PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

I source both `environment` and `.profile` but for whatever reason it doesn't work out and maven gives error that java home isn't set while it's set in 2 places even... I don't get it, `echo $JAVA_HOME` works fine too. Ubuntu is 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the path in `JAVA_HOME` should be without `/bin/java` part. Still don't know why I have to duplicate it tho, without duplicating it in `.profile` it doesn't work while it's still being in `/etc/environment`.